# ObjC: Update *label when turning back from Editing-View

Tags: objective-c

sorry for my bad english, if you don't understand me, please ask! :) 
I have a problem with Objective-C.
I try to explain my problem as easy as possible:

I made two interfaces 'profile' and 'editProfile' in 'profile.m".
I'd like to have a table (or for the beginning a *label) in profile, then I can click at 'edit' and fill in a TextField a string. With a 'save' button i save this string in a database (or an extern variable). Thats no problem, of course..
Now my problem: With clicking on 'save' i want to get back to the 'profile' page, my code:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But I want to have the IBOutlet UILabel *label  (or table) updated. This *label should show the text, which I entered in the TextField in 'editprofile'.
But it doesn't update! Parts of my code 'profile':

```
@implementation Profil
@synthesize label;
// ....
-(void) method{
 Database* db = [[Database alloc] init];
 if([db getadresse]!=nil){
    NSString *s=[db getadresse];
    label.text=s;
    [data addObject:s];
    [datadetail addObject:@"Adresse"];}
//...
```

and 'editprofil':

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender{
 Database* db = [[Database alloc] init];
 [db setadresse:TextField.text]; 
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 Profile* p= [[Profile alloc] init]; 
 [p method];}
```

What can I do to get *label updated immediately?

Thanks!

---

And what about a table in 'profile'? I want to get it refreshed.
I put the following lines in 'ViewWillApear':

```
data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   //NSMutableArrays
datadetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

database* db = [[database alloc] init];

if([db getadresse]!=nil){
    NSString *s=[db getadresse];
    [data addObject:s];
    [datadetail addObject:@"Adresse"];}


if([data count]>0){   

UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]  applicationFrame]
                                                      style:UITableViewStylePlain];
table.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
table.delegate = self;
table.dataSource = self;
[table reloadData];

self.view = table;

}
```

So the table (created in ViewWillAppear) should show the one entry of the Array ('[db.getadresse]'). But i get the Exception:

-[Profile tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x688d290

NumberOfRowsInSection is just: `return [data count]`

Can u tell me what goes wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIKit will sends the `viewWillAppear:` message to a view controller when its view appears.  Your first ("profile") view controller can update the label when it receives that message:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.label.text = code to get the text from the database;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!
Tried 'ViewDidLoad', but didn't know 'viewWillAppear'. Thank you!